# Logistic Regression- Working with categorical variable in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset that includes 7 different covariates and an output variable, the 'success rate'. 
I'm trying to find the important factors that predict the success rate. One of the covariates in my dataset is a categorical variable that takes on 700 values (0- 700), each representing the ID of the district they're from. 
How should I deal with this variable while performing logistic regression?
If I make 700 dummy columns, how can I make it easier to interpret the results? 
I'm using Python and statsmodels.

Comment: Add the data. We don't need explanation. We need data. What can we suggest without knowing how data looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply grouping and then do logistic regression on each group. Or you treat it as multilabel classifier and do "Softmax regression".